# Prove that amongst 10 sticks of length 1 to 55 there are 3 that form a triangle

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I'm trying to prove, that amongst 10 sticks, which length can vary from 1cm to 55cm, there are 3 (or at least 3), using which one can form a triangle. I feel like I should use Dirichlet's pigeon theorem here, but I'm not shure how to apply it. I know that for a triangle to be formed, sum of lengths of two sides must be greater then length of the third, but I still don't know how to apply it here.

Edit: I misread the excercise. The sticks are longer than 1cm and shorter than 55cm. No other information about the sticks is given.

Comment: Do the sticks all have to be different lengths?  You don't say that.  Without that, the statement is false.

Comment: @RossMillikan edited the question, tha sticks are longer than 1cm and shorter than 55cm

Comment: You don't need to change both bounds. It is enough if you change say an upper one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose they don't. Let that be $1\leq a_1\leq a_2\leq ...\leq a_{10}< 55$

Then by the triangle inequality we have $$1+1\leq a_1+a_2\leq  a_3\implies a_3\geq 2$$

Then $$1+2\leq a_2+a_3\leq  a_4\implies a_4\geq 3$$

and so on, we get $a_5\geq 5$, $a_6\geq 8$, $a_7\geq 13$, $a_8\geq 21$, $a_9\geq 34$ and $a_{10}\geq 55$. A contradiction.

Comment: In fact, this provides a counterexample to the claim.  Let the sticks have lengths $1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55$ and no triangle is possible.  Maybe there was supposed to be a restriction that the sticks have different lengths, but it was not stated.

Comment: @RossMillikan edited the question, tha sticks are longer than 1cm and shorter than 55cm

Comment: @RossMillikan Why is no triangle possible then? Can't a triangle have sides 3,5,8? Edit: Nevermind, It cant, I'm dumb

Comment: @greedoid It's good, thanks